# Error using stream analytics that writes to a table storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am using Azure stream analytics that writes to a table storage. When I start the job, it will eventually go to Idle mode after it starts. I check the operation logs and I see the error pasted below. I have tested the input and output connections in the stream analytics dashboard, all is good. Any ideas?

I have also checked the table storage and nothing is being written to it.

```
Correlation ID:
e6aadc96-9531-4d3d-aec0-2a6b0c2dda5d
```

Error:

> Message: Azure storage account nechealthsync table healthsamples -
>   couldn't find specified PartitionKey from event schema
>
> Message Time: 2015-03-12 05:55:00Z
>
> Microsoft.Resources/EventNameV2:
>   sharedNode92F920DE-290E-4B4C-861A-F85A4EC01D82.output-outputSink#0.output
>
> Microsoft.Resources/Operation: ProcessingTableEnities
>
> Microsoft.Resources/ResourceUri:
>   /subscriptions/56928fbb-61d5-4954-8ca7-09d46b1484d4/resourceGroups/StreamAnalytics-Default-Central-US/providers/Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/nechealthsa
>
> Type: TableOutputAdapterEntityError